# Given an isosceles triangle $АВС$ $(АВ = ВС)$ with $\angleАВС = 82^\circ$, let $М$ be a point in the interior of the triangle such that $АМ = АВ$ ...

Tags: geometry

> Given an isosceles triangle $АВС$ $(АВ = ВС)$ with $\angleАВС = 82^\circ$, let $М$ a point in the interior of the triangle such that $АМ = АВ$ and $\angle MAC = 11^\circ$. Find $\angle MCB$.

My first thought was to construct a circle of radius $AB$ passing through point B.

Below is a picture depicting what the construction of the circle would look like (Sorry if it's a bit messy!).

[image: This is what the construction looks like]

I have found that $\angle MAB=38^\circ$, which gives $\angle BDM +\angle AMD=120^\circ$, giving $\angle EDM + \angle EMD=120^\circ$. However, I am not quite sure on how to proceed here.

Comment: This is another of your question without showing your own attempt. Whatever thoughts you have, use it to draw a diagram and mark all angles you are able to find on your own. Whether the thought of constructing a circle of radius $AB$ helps or not can only be understood if you draw it and try.

Comment: If you construct the circle and get the point D of intersection with BC, it may be useful. I believe MD = MC but at the moment I don't see any way to prove it without using trigonometry.

Comment: Hi Math Lover, my apologies, I will show my own attempts next time. Ivan, thank you for your comment, sorry that I am a bit confused, but how are you able to tell that $MD = MC$?

Comment: If you want to notify someone you should use `@` infront of the name. e.g. `@yambourg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
$\triangle BDC$ is equilateral. $\angle ABD=\angle ABC-\angle 60= \angle 22 ,\angle ACD =\angle ABD/2=\angle EAC=11$ and $AE=DC$ so $AECD$ is a parallelogram and $\angle ECA=\angle DAC=\angle DBC/2 =\angle 30$ and $\angle ECB=\angle BCA-\angle ECA=49-30=19$

Comment: Right, I overlooked the fact that you could use inscribed angles for this. Thanks for the great solution!